# didSelectrow doesn't work with scrollview and tableview (iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, didselectrowatindexpath

At the moment I'm creating an app which has a scrollview and tableview. 
I used the code like here: http://johansorensen.com/articles/touches-and-uiscrollview-inside-a-uitableview.html 
but cause of the combination of the scrollview and tableview the didSelectrow function doesn't work anymore.

Thanks for helping!

Please notice: answer clear, I'm not the most experienced iOS developer.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `UIScrollView` hide your `cell`, so you can not touch cell of `UITableView` therefor `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is not work.

Write following code form your link for add `scrollView` with in `UITableView`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50.0f;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ScrollCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        UIScrollView *scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 25, 320, 25)];
        scroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

        UILabel *contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320*4, 25)];
        contentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        contentLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++) { [str appendFormat:@"%i ", i]; }
        contentLabel.text = str;

        [scroller addSubview:contentLabel];
        scroller.contentSize = contentLabel.frame.size;
        [cell addSubview:scroller];
    }


    return cell;
}
```

**and then use**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

**It may be useful for you.**